# Make access to non-existant list element an error

Tags: r

In R, one can access list elements with `$`. When one accesses a field which is not included in the list, the resulting value is just `NULL`. This is problematic in the parts of my code where I further work with object. Take this code:

```
l <- list(foo = 1, bar = 2)
print(l$foobar)
```

The output will just be `NULL` and no error and no warning. I am aware that this might be needed such that assignment of new elements (`l$foobar <- 3`) can work.

Is there some way where I can make read-access of a field in a list a hard error if it does not exist?

Comment: This is a tricky business because lists can contain ```NULL``` elements, so even defining a function that performs such a check could have undesired behavior. I'm curious if anyone or any package has implemented this.

Comment: `print(l$baz)` is `NULL` since there is no baz element ? Maybe you mean `print(l$bar)` ?

Comment: maybe this helps `"baz" %in% names(l)` ?

Comment: @Mislav: Yes, I meant `baz`, which is not in the list. I have changed it such that it is clearer now what I mean.

Comment: @dataprincess how do you gather this? If you try to assign "NULL" to a named element of a list, R deletes the element.

Comment: @AdamO for assignment, sure. I'm talking about the difficulty with access

Comment: @dataprincess I still don't understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try writing your own function:

```
extract_ls <- function(ls, el){
  if (!el %in% names(ls)) stop(paste0("The specified element ", el, " does not exist in the list"))
  else return(ls[[el]])
}
```

Then you can do:

```
extract_ls(l, "baz")
#Error in extract_ls(l, "baz") : 
# The specified element baz does not exist in the list

extract_ls(l, "bar")
#[1] 2
```

Note that I use `[[` instead of `$`. These two perform the same operation, but `$` does partial matching. Also `[[` requires a string.

---

To make this an infix function, just change the function name to `` `%[[%` ``. The usage is then:

```
l %[[% "baz"
#Error in l %[[% "baz" : 
#  The specified element baz does not exist in the list


l %[[% "bar"
#[1] 2
```

Comment: The partial matching also irritates me. This `extract_ls` function looks like the way to go, but I would prefer to have this check everywhere. So perhaps I need to define something like `%get%` which is compact to write. Or if possible even `%$%` as a checked access operator.

Comment: @MartinUeding. Sure that makes sense. It's easy enough to make this function an infix function - I can post an example if it would be helpful. Also, `%[[%` might be more accurate rather than `%$%` if you are planning on using `[[` to extract elements.

Answer (score 3):

An extreme option is to overload the `$` operator, then define an S3 method for list objects that checks the names.

```
`$` <- function(x, y) { 
  UseMethod("$")
}

`$.list` <- function(x, y) {
  ylab <- deparse(substitute(y))
  stopifnot(ylab %in% names(x))
  do.call(.Primative("$"), list(x, ylab))
}
```

Then:

```
myList <- list('a' = pi)

> myList$b
Error: ylab %in% names(x) is not TRUE

> myList$a
3.141593
```

You must, of course, be sure to set the following:

```
`$.default` <- base::`$`
```

to avoid any conflict with existing usage of the "$" operator

If you wish to continue to use partial matching with the "$" when applied to a list, you can make use of `stopifnot(length(pmatch(ylab, names(x)))>0)`.

Comment: That would replace the meaning of `$` everywhere, also in other packages? I would guess that some package depends on this just returning `NULL` in case an element does not exist, therefore it would break something else then?

Comment: @MartinUeding hmm good point, I think I wasn't explicit about setting a default method, so I updated the answer. Note very, very well that many complex R objects are essentially lists, and my method is not smart enough to look at anything that isn't a list. For instance, if I have a `lm` object called `myFit`, and I type in `myFit$coef`, I will get the coefficients, but if I type in `myFit$blabbedydoo`, I will get NULL. You don't need the object system to overload the "$" operator if you want to do that for all objects, just overload "$" with the "$.list" code I showed.

Comment: @MartinUeding the packages would only conflict if, in the package, they try to overload "$". R warns you about this. Also my gut says overloading "$" is generally a bad idea. If anyone does this in a package they should probably be arrested. But in this case, it's the only way to get exactly what you want. Use with caution.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question with an already accepted answer writing a custom function, but I think `get` from `base` R should do the trick as well:

```
l <- list(foo = 1, bar = 2)
get('foobar', l)
#> Error in get("foobar", l): object 'foobar' not found
```

Comment: That seems like a good suggestion, this can be used in the parts of the code where it should be an error. Changing the behavior of R in general might be a bit too much.

Comment: if `l` was a vector, not a list, would you suggest `get('foobar', as.list(l))`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 el_names <- function(l,variable)
       {
         if(is.null(l[[variable]]) & length(l)>1)               
           {

            stop("Null found")
           }
        else{
            print(l[[variable]])
            }
       }


> el_names(l,"foo")
[1] 1
```

Comment: `names` is already a function in base R. It might be best to not overwrite it. This could give some unwanted behavior if you do.

Comment: I think `stop` takes a string itself, no need to have `print` in it. Also this will fail with a list like `list(x = NULL)` where there actually is an element which is `NULL`.

Comment: My apologies. .